# App translations are not working after downloading it from Store

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal

I am having a problem where my app translations work on my pc when I set different language with `ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride`, but after the same app is uploaded into Microsoft Store and downloaded from there - translations stop working. As a default it uses English language and ignores other selected languages.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are generating an app bundle during Store package creation, the language-specific resources, different image scaling options, etc. are exported to separate packages to minimize the app package size that has to be downloaded by the user. This however means, that the system will download only the languages it deems required. So if you don't add the target language in the list in the **Region & Language** area of system settings, it won't probably be downloaded as part of the app package and hence switching to it manually using `PrimaryLanguageOverride` will have no effect. However note that when you add the language, the system will later download the language-specific resources automatically from the Store, so it will then be available.